# Calendar that skips weekend and holidays?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Imagine Google Calendar. Add an event that will take 7 days. It starts on today and goes on for 7 days, not skipping weekends or holidays.

I need a calendar that will assume those are WORKING days.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you are contradicting yourself in your question and title. In one, you ask for a "Calendar that skips weekend and holidays" and in the other you say "not skipping weekends or holidays". Which is it? This is confusing and may not even be on-topic for this site.

Comment: It was confusing. The first bit there is what google calendar does, the question is what he wants.

Comment: Checkout [supplebee.com](https://supplebee.com). It allows you to create recurring events on business days only, avoiding public holidays and weekends

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with Google Calendar by setting a repeat event and restrict by days and number of occurrences:

use settings like this for the repeat:

[image: Calendar settings]

And it will skip weekends (since you didn't select them to repeat)
you can see by the bold dates that it skipped the weekend

[image: cal small]

As for skipping holidays, you'll have to pick them manually when you're setting the "repeat on:" days.

Comment: The events aren't repeating events. Let's say I have to work on the website for 7 working days. I'd like the task to start today, skip any weekend or holiday and keep going the following week.

Comment: Well, that's what it does. Since you didn't check the Saturday or Sunday boxes it pretends they don't exist. It'll begin at your start date and end after X occurrences skipping weekends every time. Or am I just not understanding the requirement?